# Which protocol I should conform to add one generic value to another in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, protocols

I've created a struct called 'Code', which contains a string and generic property. So, now I'm trying to create a method, which is going to work with the array of Code elements. But the problem is that I'm not aware about the protocol that T-elements should conform to perform + operator.

```
struct Code<Element>{
   let probability: Element
   let code: String
}

func createTree<T>(_ array: [Code<T>]){

    for i in 0..<array.count-1{
       let sum = array[i].probability + array[i+1].probability
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide the code for your struct?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry surely, I've added one

Answer (score 0):

`Arithmetic` is the protocol you are after. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/arithmetic

Comment: But note that's only available since Swift 3.1.